# Get data from array

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

Hello I am new to codeigniter framework, and I need help do get some data from array that is forwarded to my view.
In my controller's method I was load model who returns me data array from db, and than I pass that data to my view, and that looks like this:

```
 function deleteAccount($data){
    $this->load->model('model_admin');
    $dataFromModel = array();
    if($query = $this->model_admin->retrieveAccount ($data)){
        $dataFromModel['records'] = $query;
        $this->load->view('admin/test',$dataFromModel);
    }  else {
        echo "No data was returned";
    }

}
```

and in my view i manage to retrieve that data and to echo it like this:

```
<?php
echo "TEST page<br/>";


if(isset($records)) {
    foreach ($records as $row) {

        echo $row->username;    
    }
}  else {
    echo "No data";
}
?>
```

But I am certain that if I retrieve data from db it is either one line or no lines at all, so in my view page i would like to echo that data without foreach loop on some way, for example like this:

```
echo $records->username;
```

or:

```
echo $records[0]; //because it is the first argument in line
```

but in both ways it throws an error :

1 - first case: Trying to get property of non-object

2 - second case: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

This is my model:

```
function retrieveAccount($data){ 
$query = $this->db->get_where('table_users', array('username' => $data[2]));     

return $query->result(); }
```

Can someone help me, and show me how to retrieve that data.

Comment: does the `$records` contains any tag by username?? Can you print that variable and check.??

Comment: Can you post your models code??

Comment: function retrieveAccount($data){
        
        $query = $this->db->get_where('table_users', array('username' => $data[2]));
        
        return $query->result();
    }

Comment: can you edit  your model code into your question

Comment: you are call form controller `deleteAccount` function and show us `retrieveAccount` ??

Comment: it was deleteAccount but i call it here retrieveAccount to avoid confusions, but when you ask from me to insert model here, i was made an mistake. Mistake is corrected now, i just want to echo somehow data on my test page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you want to use **$records->username** this means **$records** must contain only one value. In this case instead of using **$query->result()**, use **$query->row()** in your model code.
2. You cannot echo stdClass object. $records[0] is stdClass object thus Php is giving this error. Instead this would work

   echo $records[0]->username